# Oracle Stored Procedure PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, oracle10g, runtime-error

I am receiving the following oracle errors:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERT_CATEGORY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I read over this error and people say that if you are passing a different value type to the stored procedure type can make this error but it doesn't seem to be the case for me.

[image]

Most of my coding is almost identical to what I have(and they worked). Only difference with this one is I am using a Boolean as well so I am not sure if that is causing the issues too.

```vb
Protected Sub BtnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNew.Click
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=""*******"";user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd)

    If Page.IsValid Then

        If CatText.Text <> "" Then


            Dim ClassifiedStr As New OleDbCommand

            ClassifiedStr.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            'name of stored procedure = 'insert_category'
            ClassifiedStr.CommandText = "insert_category"
            ClassifiedStr.Connection = conn

            'Must be organized based on Stored Procedure
            ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_category", OleDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = CatText.Text
            conn.Open()

            'Makes sure the Category doesn't already exist****************
            Dim myParm As OleDbParameter = ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_newcat", OleDbType.Boolean)
            myParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            ClassifiedStr.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'myParm needs Execute
            Dim standardid As Integer = myParm.Value
            '***********************************************

            If standardid = False Then

                conn.Close()

                Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Thanks! Record Has Been Added.');</script>")
                Response.Redirect("DisplayCategories.aspx")
            Else
                Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Sorry! Record Already Exist.');</script>")
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Else
            Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('You must insert a record.');</script>")
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Stored Procedure

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_category
(val_category        TABLENAME.Category%type, 
 val_newcat out boolean) 

as num_catid number;  

begin   

select category_seq.nextval into num_catid from dual;   

  INSERT INTO TABLENAME  
   (select num_catid, val_category from TABLENAME WHERE Category != val_Category);  

commit; 

  val_newcat := SQL%FOUND; 

end;
```

Comment: Change your stored procedure to use a merge, that way the SP can determine if it should insert or update. That would also clean up your VB.

Comment: Change your `TABLENAME.Category%type` to `varchar2`. Remember, you using OleDb, which is not ideal. Switch to ODP.net for oracle.

Comment: I have never done a merge one before, however I have done stored procedures like the one above and they worked fine. (so I don't think I have to use merge) Also @T.S. my other stored procedures use %type with no issues. Just for some reason I have issues with this one

Comment: @Chuck I will look into the merge version though and see if I have to use it (might take me a little bit)

Comment: Actually, I think, I know what is your problem. Boolean is pl/sql type that can be used in code but most likely a problem using as output parameter. Make your output parameter number and pass 1 for true and 0 for false. Again, ODP.NET may understood this type but you use OleDB so, you shoot yourself into foot. Besides that OleDB will not be supported eventually. I asked you to use varchar2 to hardwire parameter to make sure there is no discrepancy there.

Comment: I tried something along those lines like `val_newcat := case SQL%FOUND when TRUE then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end;` but gave more issues. I think I am going to remove Boolean and make allow duplicates because the administrators know not to make duplicates.

Comment: I don't know what "more issues" you incurred by making out parameter varchar2, but I would see one issue if you changed nothing in code. When processing varchar2 as output parameter, you need to set parameter size.

Comment: Also, `val_newcat := case...` --> oh-oh. This is pl/sql --> `If .... then ... else .. end if;`.  `case` is for in-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates that fixed issue:

```
Dim ClassifiedStr As New OleDbCommand

ClassifiedStr.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
'name of stored procedure = 'insert_category'
ClassifiedStr.CommandText = "insert_category"
ClassifiedStr.Connection = conn

'Must be organized based on Stored Procedure
ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_category", OleDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = CatText.Text
conn.Open()

'Makes sure the Category doesn't already exist
Dim myParm As OleDbParameter = ClassifiedStr.Parameters.Add("val_newcat", OleDbType.VarChar, 10)
myParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

ClassifiedStr.ExecuteNonQuery()
'myParm needs Execute before declared

Dim standardid As String = myParm.Value

'***********************************************

If standardid = "TRUE" Then

    conn.Close()
    etc....
```

Stored Procedure:

```
(val_category        t_category.Category%type,     
val_newcat out varchar2)     

as num_catid number;      

begin       

select newCategory_seq.nextval into num_catid from dual;         

INSERT INTO TABLENAME      
select num_catid, val_category from dual WHERE not exists (select * from TABLENAME where Category = val_Category);      

val_newcat := case SQL%FOUND when TRUE then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end;    

commit;     

end;
```